# Pettitt's Test for Change-Point Detection Showing P-Value Larger than 1

Tags: r, time-series, p-value, trend, change-point

I am studying how to use the `pettitt.test` function from the `trend` package in R to detect change-point in a time-series. However, after testing this function on some example datasets, I noticed that sometimes the p-value is larger than one. Below is an example.

```
library(trend)

# Example vector
vec <- c(-0.2, -0.2, -1.8, -0.3, 1.5, -0.2, -0.2, 1.2, -1, 1.2, -1, -0.5, 1.1, -1.2)

pettitt.test(vec)
```

```
        Pettitt's test for single change-point detection

data:  vec
U* = 17, p-value = 1.109
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
probable change point at time K 
                             10
```

I thought the p-value should be a number from 0 to 1. Are there any reasons why this function generates a p-value larger than 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *true* p-value is a probability, so you are correct that it must be between zero and one.  However, according to the [documentation for the `trend` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/trend/versions/1.1.1/topics/pettitt.test), this test uses an *approximate* p-value$^\dagger$:

$$\hat{p} = 2 \cdot \exp \Bigg( -\frac{6 K^2}{T^3+T^2} \Bigg).$$

The documentation notes that this approximation is only good for $\hat{p} \leqslant \tfrac{1}{2}$.  In this case the value is not even within the allowable bounds, so it is clear that the approximation is not good!

---

$^\dagger$ Another problem is that the reported p-value in the output does not match the formula reported in the documentation.  In your output you have `U* = 17`, `K = 10` and `T = 17`, which should give the approximate p-value `p-value = 1.631`.  However, the reported `p-value = 1.109` matches a value of `K = 17`, not `K = 10`.  This suggests that there may be a problem either with the documentation or the function itself.